# How to pass multiple prop in image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a react demo with JSON to create multiple components using the JSON. But the problem is how do I pass multiple images inside the component.

For example

I can create multiple components and pass the prop so it can act as one, two, three, etc accordion. But the problem is inside each accordion body I want to have a dynamic image corresponding to that accordion title using JSON in App.js Products. To be briefer one accordion can have one 3 image and second accordion to have 5 image for example. Could someone guide me on how to apply that logic. New to react.

Even Simpler explanation if it's confusing

1. First Accordion to have 5 images
2. Second Accordion to have 3 images
3. Want to create an accordion with x amount of image using JSON

Thank you

[Demo of the App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ky7zep)

Comment: Because you should not include the code by pasting a link to a third party site. Put the code in your post. Preferably in a Stack Snippet using the button with `<>` on it.

Comment: My first time using react I have seen a lot of people using jsFiddle link, codepen how is that valid ? The reason its 3rd party link because it use different component to fetch the data I don't know hows that possible in stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to add a few adjustments to make it work.
App.js

```
 const products = [
    {
      title: "First Accordion",
      body: "I am just a body hiddent untill someone clicked on me",
      linkUrl: [
        {
          'url': "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg"
        },
        {
          'url': "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg"
        },
      ],
      linktitle: "Google Link"
    },
    {
      title: "Second Accordion",
      body: "I am just a body hiddent untill someone clicked on me",
      linkUrl: [
        {
          'url': "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg"
        }
      ],
      linktitle: "Google Link"
    }
  ]
```

Accordion.js

````
   {linkUrl.map(product => (
     <img src={product.url} alt="Avatar" classname="image" />
   ))}```
````